# How to select a record from a recordset with maximum field value?

Tags: ms-access, vba, max, recordset

I have a table "rd_details" as follows:

```
GNo     RD      ROI 
11     1000    11.75
12     2000    11.75
12     5020    11.75
12     2100    11.75
11     3000    11.75
11     4000    11.75
```

My result should be

for GNo. 11, I should get 11, 4000, 11.75
for GNo. 12, I should get 12, 5020, 11.75

These are records with maximum value of the RD.
when I key in GNo as 11  I should get RD as 4000 and ROI as 11.75

I have the following query. I am using MS Access with VBA.

```
Set rst1 = dbs.OpenRecordset("select * from rd_details where gno=" & Gno)
```

Kindly modify the above query keeping the `where` clause unchanged..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you edit your post to add formatting so it is easier to read? Use the code tag for your code.

Comment: All you need to do is to add [HAVING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177906%28v=office.12%29.aspx) clause.

Comment: @MaciejLos would having work in this case without a Group By? I think he needs to apply a rank.

Comment: @MichaelZ., MS Access does not know ranking functions. There's a way to workaround it, but simple MAX function may meet OP's criteria.

Comment: Nested query would solve this. I just don't feel like writing it.

Comment: Why down vote this?

Comment: @KyloRen I don't agree with the down-vote either.

Comment: @MichaelZ., glad to see I am not the only one.up vote for you first comment

Answer (score 2):

You can [aggregate data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177686%28v=office.12%29.aspx) within MS Acces database engine. In this case, you have to use `MAX` function.

```
select GNO, MAX(RD) AS RD, ROI
from rd_details
group by GNO, ROI
```

Another way (as [Michael Z.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4114591/michael-z) mentioned in the comment to the question) is to use nested query.

```
select a.GNO, a.RD, b.ROI
from rd_details AS b INNER JOIN
    (select GNO, MAX(RD) AS RD
    from rd_details
    group by GNO) AS a ON b.GNO = a.GNO AND b.RD = a.RD
```

Comment: I like this simple approach, but I don't think it would work if `ROI` had different values.

Comment: @MichaelZ., i added another solution ;) Thank you.

Comment: Do you need the max `RD` for a specific `GNO` and `ROI` value set or do you need the record where `RD` is the max for a specific `GNO` only? The solutions above are not the same, one does the first and the other the second.

Comment: @SunKnight0, Sorry, but i don't get you... There's at least few ways to achieve what OP want to get.

Comment: He needs the entire record for the `Max(RD)` for each `Gno`

Comment: In that case the first of the two above solutions will not work as it groups by `ROI`.

Comment: @MichaelZ.second sample has been changed to OP requirements. Thanks for your valuable comments!

Comment: @SunKnight0, OK, got it. Thank you for your valuable comment!

Comment: That does not work properly either. You should add `AND b.RD=a.RD` at the end of it for it to work properly. You will also probably get an error for `b.ROI` as it needs to be added to the `GROUP BY` or do something like `FIRST(b.ROI)`

Comment: @SunKnight0, hawk eye! Added!

Comment: Seems, you worked at the first version of second solution. I replaced `a` with `b` and `b` with `a` ;)